# Select-query to db

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, cancan

I want to execute a SQL-query and apply the result to my ability-class:

```
res_sql = "SELECT * FROM people 
             where trainer_id != null and people.user_id = user.id 
             and user.role = 'Trainerone'"
```

The sql should return Objects from Typ Sportler that I can apply it to cancan:

```
can :manage, **:sportler**
```

Comment: I cant prepare my querstion. So on: I have an idea: maybe this but it's only for one class. People.find_all_by_trainer_id_and_user_id(not null, 2) but there is no relationship to user

Comment: You're missing a join to the 'user' table.

Comment: Please stop adding tags to the question subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understood your question but maybe this can help you a little bit:

```
People.joins(:trainer).
       includes(:user).
       where(user_id: user.id, user: { role: 'Trainerone' })
```

This code implis the following:

- Trainer `has_many` People
- People `belongs_to` Trainer
- People `belongs_to` User
- `role` is a column of the User table
  (the different relations in `joins` and `includes` (and so in the where clause) may need to be pluralized, depending on your Object-relations)

Comment: nice rails has his own syntax. I did this myTrainer = People.joins.... And then i want to set this in cancan: can :manage, myTrainer would this work?